# How to compile LaTeX with C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, latex

is there a way to compile a LaTeX document with C#?

I want to program a standalone Windows application, that gives you a pdf-file without installing any other programs like miktex/etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why LaTeX? For simply creating some PDF documents, you may rely on smaller NuGet Solutions.

If you really want to use LaTeX without system install dependency, it will come with some work. You could check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168652/embed-tex-live-into-application and related threads in tex.stackexchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LaTeX is similar to using a programming language or markup language, like HTML. You'll have to reimplement everything from LaTeX that you want to support in your C# program. This might be possible for a very small subset of the LaTeX standard, but you'll be reinventing the wheel. LaTeX is the most extensive markup language around with an enormous feature set with decades of development, it's not feasible to create a C# converter out of the blue for it.

To put it bluntly, it would be probably easier for you to create your own C# compiler than to come up with a feature complete LaTeX compiler.

If you can't change your input data, i.e. a LaTeX source, then you should use one of the existing LaTeX converters. If you're looking for a way to convert text source files with some markup data to PDF with C# then better look into a lightweight markup language like Markdown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it then possible, to compile through miktex with C#? For example, I create a tex-file with C# and fire the compile command through a bash script or something like that.

Comment: You can call a LaTeX interpreter with [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx). Look at the `OpenWithArguments()` example over there for some inspiration.

Comment: Thank you. If this is the only way to compile it without "reinventing the wheel" then it's the way to go.